# OCTAVE: Checking existence of an element of a cell array

Tags: octave, exists

I am using Octave 4.0.0.

I define `A{1, 1} = 'qwe'`, but when I check existence of `A{1, 1}`, as in

```
 exist("A{1,1}")
```

or

```
exist("A{1,1}", "var")
```

it returns 0.

How can I check its existence?

Comment: Checking the existence of an element like that is meaningless. Check if the array exists, and if it has a size sufficient to contain that element

Comment: Note that `"A{1,1}"` is not a valid variable name, so it cannot exist. It is a statement, not a variable name.

Comment: @MadPhysicist well, it is pretty meaningful in my current code; I am reading a large number of files, then storing in cells and indexing them depending on whether or not they include certain numbers in certain positions in their names. Hence, there is a possibility of some indices of cells remaining empty, and the cell itself existing does not help.

Comment: Are you looking for the `isempty` function?

Comment: depending on whether or not they include certain numbers in certain positions in their names@HüseyinCanÖnel After your last comment with "filenames in cell ... " sounds that you are rather looking for regexp or some string compare/parse function

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes, maybe checking if it is empty or not is a better idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if an array has element say `3, 5`, you need to verify that the array has at least 3 rows and 5 columns:

```
all(size(A) >= [3, 5])
```

You can of course check if variable `A` exists at all before-hand, and also is a cell array. A complete solution might be something like

```matlab
function b = is_element(name, varargin)

b = false;

if ~evalin(['exists("' name '")'], 'caller')
    return;
end

if ~strcmp(evalin(['class(' name ')'], 'caller'), 'cell')
    return;
end

if evalin(['ndim(' name ')'], 'caller') ~= nargin - 1
    return;
end

b = all(evalin(['size(' name ')'], 'caller') >= cell2mat(varargin))

endfunction
```

This function accepts a variable name and the multi-dimensional index you are interested in. It returns 1 if the object exists as a cell array of sufficient dimensionality and size to contain the requested element.

Comment: Given the last comment you left on your question, I'd say that this answer is slightly incomplete. You should have no trouble incorporating a check of the cell value into the function I've provided.

Comment: On a related note, you're quite welcome. The proper way to thank is by selecting the answer by clicking on the check mark next to it.